# create exact instance from class name

Tags: c#

i have two classes: `Class1` and `Class2`

```
class Class1
{
    public void method();
}

class Class2
{
    public void method();
}
```

in another place I have the class type and I want to create an instance from it.
type is `typeof(Class1`) or `typeof(Class2)`

```
public void CreateInstance(Type type)
{
    var instance = Activator.GetInstance(type);
    instance.method(); //compile error: object doesn't contain method
}
```

a solution is I define an interface that my classes implement that interface.

```
interface IInterface
{
    void method();
}

public void CreateInstance(Type type)
{
    var instance = Activator.GetInstance(type);
    ((IInterface)instance).method();
}
```

because I can't access to class definition I can't do this. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `dynamic` instead of `var` as a quick&dirty solution. What do you mean that you can't access the definitions though? You mean that you can't modify them?

Comment: He probably means that he doesn't implement the classes himself. Probably they come from some sort of library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
public void CreateInstance(Type type)
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    type.GetMethod("method").Invoke(instance, null);
}
```

Or, alternatively, use `dynamic`:

```
public void CreateInstance(Type type)
{
    dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    instance.method();
}
```

NB: You had `GetInstance` instead of `CreateInstance` in your code, but I corrected it.

Comment: You were a minute faster ;)

Comment: Or use `dynamic`. Any type safety is already lost and dynamic is easier (and faster) than reflection

Comment: I think the first solution is better. because I can check method really exist.

Comment: @mohammad not really - what are you going to do if it doesn't? Throwing an exception is the same as detecting the missing method and trying to work around it in this case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Worst case, you can throw a more appropriate exception.

Comment: @Rawling it doesn't get more appropriate than the purpose-built  [RuntimeBinderException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.runtimebinderexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Catching and rethrowing this to an application specific exception isn't hard either. Nothing changes really, except that reflection always pays a performance penalty, even if there are no issues. Worse, you *can* forget to check for the method, resulting in a much worse `NullReferenceException` or even erroneous execution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - No, don't rethrow or even allow the exception. This isn't an exceptional case. It's something that can, and should, be programmed to avoid. Eric Lippert calls these kinds of exceptions **boneheaded** and says that if you can avoid them but don't then they are bugs in your code. Read this: http://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @Enigmativity you may say that the OP's code is buggy then, as the only way to avoid such problems is to use strong typing. Trying to call a non-existent method though *is* an exceptional case and probably *is* a bug - the wrong type was passed, or the method call is wrong. Whether you use reflection and a null check, or catch the exception that says the method is missing - *why was the wrong type passed and what should be done about it* ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - It's not exceptional at all. You can check if the method exists with a simple `if` statement. We have no idea what the logic is or what the method does. All we can do is suggest what the right way to handle the situation if the method is missing.

Comment: @Enigmativity what is the right way? Gobble it or return 0, false or -1? How can processing continue if a call failed because of a missing method? What happens when this error propagates and eg. you end up with a `-1` exchange rate and `-100%`  performance on a customer's portfolio statement? (true story)

Comment: BTW your code will throw NullReferenceException without any info if the method is missing - it *is* treating this as exceptional but it isn't providing any info. Using `dynamic` will throw `RuntimeBinderException` specifying the missing method.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - You're being argumentative. I did say that we have no idea what the required logic is. If we did we could suggest what to do. But that doesn't change the fact that we should strive to write code that doesn't throw exceptions. That's what the OP should be doing. It would be wrong for us to suggest he throw an exception. We just don't know what his logic requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid reflection and performance issues entirely by using a generic method and `dynamic`:

```
public void CreateInstance<T>() where T:new()
{
    dynamic instance=new T();
    instance.method();
}
```

Which you can call simply by passing the type:

```
CreateInstance<Class1>();
CreateInstance<Class2>();
```

Type safety is lost either when using reflection or using `dynamic`. Checking for the existence of a method with reflection isn't any safer or less risky than having the runtime throw an exception - in both cases you have to handle an exceptional condition. What *are* you going to do when this exception occurs?

With `dynamic`, a missing method will raise a [RuntimeBinderException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.runtimebinderexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifying that a method is missing. If I changed the method call from `method` to `method1` I'll get an exception saying:

> 'ConsoleApplication24.Class1' does not contain a definition for 'method1'

This way the code does *not* pay the reflection penalty for the normal cases. This is also safer - there is no way that the exception can be missed.

The only way that provides compile-type safety is to have the classes implement an interface and use it as a generic constraint, eg:

```
public static void CreateInstance<T>() where T : ISomething, new()
{
    var instance = new T();
    instance.method();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to use interface for safety. But if you can't do that, you can invoke this method through reflection:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("executed");
    }
}

public class MyActivator
{
    public static void CreateInstance(Type type)
    {
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        var method = GetMethod("method");
        method.Invoke(instance, null);
    }
}
```

And then you call this by:

```
MyActivator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass));
```

Remember to add some checking if method is not null

Comment: Why such a complicated call? You don't need to search for the method, just call `GetMethod`. Better yet, use `dynamic`

Comment: Yes - added at the same time